# What does [or strsql] mean in my query? What does +"0" change in the first line?

Tags: sql, where-clause, sql-like

Here is a piece of my code, I have several questions. I didn't write it and I don't understand what +"0" does in the first line. T is a numerical value that can go from 0 to 3.

What does the [or strsql] and [and strsql] do? What I understand is that [] represents a box field in the input mask, so a condition that has to be met.

The code is only SQL as far as I know its not strsql code (that is another language I think) nor VBA.

Thank you very much.

```
WHERE 
(
(
( 
((tbl_cases.t<>"")+"0" LIKE '[mit T-wert 0/1]%')
AND 
(tbl_cases.case_id LIKE '%[year_Cases]%')
)
)
AND 
(tbl_cases.archiv=0)   
AND
(
('[age from 18 (0/1)]'="1" and age not in ("ersmal Schellösung","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","") and age is not null) 
 or '[Age from 18 (0/1)]'=""
 or ('[Alter ab 18 (0/1)]'="0" and age in ("ersmal Schellösung","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17")) 
) [and strsql] 
) [or strsql]
```

Comment: As this isn't VBA code, please remove the vba tag

Comment: when it is there. what is it exactly doing?

Comment: the tag [strsql] is ever used in sql or not?

Comment: its not a SQl syntax that i know of. SQL server, oracle and mysql (to mention a few) will have slightly different syntax . it does appear it might be a string expression for the where condition passed to your sql code using the strsql variable.

Comment: Looks like partially constructed string for building SQL. There is probably a host program module further replacing parts of it to turn it into a valid `WHERE` clause

Comment: Do you know what the +"0" in the first like do?

Comment: Only a guess: maybe it causes the result of `tbl_cases.t<>""` (assume to be Boolean) to be cast into a string that can be used as the first operand of operator `LIKE`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.